# Xcode Build errors repeated twice

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm running Xcode 13.2.1 and I've noticed that I'm getting build errors repeated twice in the panel. Has anyone come across this before or know of how to solve this as it might explain the reason why my Xcode is acting sluggish.

[image: Xcode repeating build errors]

Comment: Can you tell us how to make a project that behaves like this? Are you building multiple architectures simultaneously? — another way to think about it: Does this happen with a new clean project? If not, think about the difference between that project and yours. Look carefully at the structure and build settings.

Comment: @matt - I'm not running multiple architectures, but I have noticed a few times Xcode gets "hung up" on multiple builds of the same app inside the top centre bar which ends up needing a force quit. The app only has one target with a unit tests target using a test plan, not that this would create multiple builds at the same time.

Comment: That doesn't sound good either. I work on some quite large projects but I've never seen that. Do you do frequent DerivedData cleans to keep your project healthy?

Comment: @matt I do frequent cleans, and just double checked and the architectures is set to $(ARCHS_STANDARD). Also nothing out of the ordinary in build phases.

Comment: Well, the point is, you are not giving _us_ enough information to help. I'm afraid that _you_ have to investigate the cause of the issue, in the way that I suggested: compare your structure to the structure of a project that does _not_ have this issue.

Comment: @matt - that's fine, I wondered if anyone had experienced this before or at the very least knew where to start looking. The project is a medium growing to large so as you know it would help if someone had an idea :)

Answer (score 2):

So after much fact finding and head scratching the issue was down to having the "show live issues" checked inside `Preferences->General`. It's not necessarily a fix, but it keeps errors only visible when building the project.